# No visible @interface for 'UIInterpolatingMotionEffect' declares the selector 'initWithKeyPath:type:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimotioneffect

I am having and issue with `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` class, the app compiles but when I try to archive I got this compilation error:

`No visible @interface for 'UIInterpolatingMotionEffect' declares the selector 'initWithKeyPath:type:'`

I got this error on the initialisers of `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` on this function:

```
- (void)addMotionEffects
{
    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
                                                           initWithKeyPath:@"center.x" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];

    horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-20);
    horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(20);

    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
                                                         initWithKeyPath:@"center.y" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
    verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-20);
    verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(20);

    UIMotionEffectGroup *group = [UIMotionEffectGroup new];
    group.motionEffects = @[horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect];
    [self.containerView addMotionEffect:group];
}
```

I think is a kind of error when trying to compile for arm64 architectures, but I can not figure it out how to solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you building to support iOS 6 as well, by chance?

Comment: Nop, deployment target is iOS7 and Base SDK iOS8.1

Comment: May this link would help you..
http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/introduction-to-uimotioneffect/

Comment: My implementation is correct, is not a problem of the code of the UIMotionEffect itself, because this builds properly and works on my iPhone. The problem is that the same code do not compile when archiving and I don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a WTF answer as well as it was a WTF question, but works...

To avoid the compilation error I have created a category for `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` with the selector that give the error. But still don't know why Xcode do not archive without this...

```
@interface UIInterpolatingMotionEffect (lol)
- (instancetype)initWithKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath type:(UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType)type;
@end
```